# Make phone calls from my app instead of the default phone app

Tags: android, phone-call

The feature I want to implement is: make a phone call from my own app instead of using the system's default phone app.
I read that this is done using intents.

Most of the times, people are using intents to popup the system's phone app to handle the call.
But, I want to do that myself. 
The call will be initiated from my app only.
So this is not for calls from other apps.

In short, the user will dial a number from my app and my app itself will make a call (cellular network) and handle it.
From [this blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/05/handling-phone-call-requests-right-way.html), it seems to be possible.
Is it really? How?

Comment: Downvoters, comments please?

Comment: I think it can be possible with a rooted device. But I haven't found any tutorial. Did you solve it?

Comment: @Tiger: No, still unsolved. I would like to see how it will work on rooted device though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Its not possible in Android OS (Edit Below API level 26)**

If you are running your app on a registered Android device then you have to follow their terms which is not allowing your app to handle calls on your own.

FYI: *The cellular call depends more on hardware than software.*

---

### Edit

In API level 26 (Oreo) they have introduce new API.
The [ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS) permission allows your app to answer incoming phone calls programmatically. To handle an incoming phone call in your app, you can use the [acceptRingingCall()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/TelecomManager.html#acceptRingingCall()) method.

Just to be noted

'These permission are both classified as [dangerous](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous) and are both part of the PHONE permission group.'

Comment: Not knowing myself how to solve the problem, this answer seems to miss the point. It claims that the problem cannot be solved below API 26 because of "their terms". However starting from API 1, Android does have a [CALL_PHONE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CALL_PHONE) permission. Where does it say that I am not supposed to use it? Starting from API 26, "they have introduced a new API", but while the question was about outgoing calls, the answer is about incoming ones.